# How to make an UIAlertView pop up when a bouncing image touches a draggable image?

Tags: ios

How can I pop up alert when an bouncing image touches a draggable image the same way it's done in this app: http://tinyurl.com/kspnh6

Example: there is an image that is going up and down the screen and it touches an image that we can drag around. How can we show an alert view when that image touches the moving image?

Answer (score 1):

When you move the dragged view around, check the updated frame property against that of the other items.

You can use a function such as [CGRectIntersectsRect](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntersectsRect) to determine if the frame of any two views overlap each other (i.e. when it's time to show the alert).

This acheives a rectangular "hit test", there would be more work involved if you wanted the hit test to respect rounded shapes etc.